# IndexError when accessing a certain column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When trying to access the `label` column, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NeryDragos/PycharmProjects/Song-Recommendation-System/python_src/model.py", line 117, in <module>
    sr = SongReccomender('../Data/final.csv')
  File "C:/Users/NeryDragos/PycharmProjects/Song-Recommendation-System/python_src/model.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.train_and_add_categorical_columns()
  File "C:/Users/NeryDragos/PycharmProjects/Song-Recommendation-System/python_src/model.py", line 63, in train_and_add_categorical_columns
    self.data['label'] = self.km.labels_
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


# from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

class SongReccomender:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        self.remove_categorical_Data()
        self.pca()
        self.train_and_add_categorical_columns()

    def remove_categorical_Data(self):
        self.cols = ['artist', 'danceability', 'energy', 'key', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'acousticness',
                     'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo', 'duration_ms', 'time_signature', 'label']
        self.non_categorical = ['danceability', 'energy', 'loudness', 'speechiness', 'acousticness', 'instrumentalness',
                                'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo', 'duration_ms']
        self.categorical = ['artist', 'key', 'mode', 'time_signature', 'label']

        # %ms = MinMaxScaler()
        self.df[self.non_categorical] = self.df[self.non_categorical].apply(
            lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))

    def pca(self):
        pca = PCA(0.95)
        self.data = self.df.drop_duplicates()
        self.data = pca.fit_transform(self.data[self.non_categorical])
        # cluster_plot(pd.DataFrame(self.data))
        pd.DataFrame(self.data).head()
        return

    def train(self, df_train):
        n = 1
        for _ in range(n):
            self.km = KMeans(
                n_clusters=4, init='random',
                n_init=10, max_iter=1000,
                tol=1e-04, random_state=0
            )
            y_km = self.km.fit(df_train)
        return self.km

    def k_mean_distance(self, center_coordinates, data_coordiantes):
        summ = 0
        mag = 0
        for i in range(len(center_coordinates)):
            summ += (center_coordinates[i] - data_coordiantes[i]) ** 2
            mag += (data_coordiantes[i]) ** 2
        return (summ) * 0.5

    def train_and_add_categorical_columns(self):
        self.train(self.data)
        # pickle.dump(km, open('KMeans_Clustering', 'wb'))
        self.data['label'] = self.km.labels_
        self.data['artist'] = self.df.artist
        self.data['name'] = self.df.name
        self.data['preview'] = self.df.preview
        self.data['popularity'] = self.df.popularity
        self.data['type'] = self.df.label
        self.data.head()

    def song_recommendation(self, song, data):
        arr = []
        dummy_df = data.loc[data['label'] == song.label.values[0]]
        print(len(dummy_df.values))
        for i in range(len(dummy_df.values)):
            if (i > 51): break
            dist = self.k_mean_distance(dummy_df.values[i][0:7], song.values[0][0:7])
            arr.append((
                dummy_df.values[i][11] / (dist + 0.00000001) ** 2,
                dist,
                dummy_df.values[i][11],
                dummy_df.values[i][8],
                dummy_df.values[i][9],
                dummy_df.values[i][10],
                dummy_df.values[i][12]
            ))
        arr.sort()
        return arr

    def song_print(self, song):
        print('=' * 200)
        print('Artist:  ', song.artist.values[0])
        print('Song Name:   ', song.name.values[0])
        print('Type:   ', song['type'].values[0])
        print('Preview link:   ', song.preview.values[0])
        print('=' * 200)

    def print_song_reccomendation(self, song_number):
        # song = self.data.loc[[2980]]
        song = self.data.loc[[song_number]]
        ans = self.song_recommendation(song, self.data)
        self.song_print(song)
        j = 1
        for i in ans[::-1]:
            print('Number:  ', j)
            print('Popularity/distance:  ', i[0])
            print('Artist:  ', i[3])
            print('Song Name:   ', i[4])
            print('Type:   ', i[6])
            print('Preview link:   ', i[5])
            print('-' * 100)
            j += 1
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sr = SongReccomender('../Data/final.csv')
    sr.print_song_reccomendation(song_number=2980)
```

Comment: Did you read the error? It even shows where it happens and what types are acceptable there... That said, you shouldn't dump your whole code here (it's not even complete, since the data is missing!) but instead extract a [mcve].

Comment: Can you print self.df? or self.data?

Comment: `self.data['label'] = self.df.label` doesn't exist in your code. Either `self.data['label']` is assigned something else or it should be `self.data['type']`. You need to show us the actual code that produced this error.

Comment: @enke It looks like ``self.data['label'] = self.df.label`` doesn't exist in my code.

Comment: so where do you get that error from?

Comment: @enke Didn't I just provide the info on where I get the error?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I kind of get it requires integers, but I don't understand why and besides  how should I provide the data? Since all I can provide is a ``.csv`` which may look kind of ugly.

Comment: @Neri-kun the traceback says the error occurs on line 63 `self.data['label'] = self.df.label` which should be part of your `train_and_add_categorical_columns` method, however, from your code, that method doesn't contain such line. Such inconsistency indicates that the code you provided here did not produce the traceback you provided here. I suggest you to check again, and make sure to run the code, see the traceback, copy that code and copy that traceback here.

Comment: traceback has `self.data['label'] = self.df.label`. Your code has `self.data['label'] = self.km.labels_` and `self.data['type'] = self.df.label` but they are not what the traceback has.

Comment: @RaymondKwok Yep. You're right. Thing is I tried experimenting some things and I forgot maybe to rerun the code after making that change on the line of code. Nonetheless, I still get the same error if you can check the edit I made on my question.

Comment: The error implies that `self.data` is a numpy array, not a dataframe.  It is set in `pca` with `self.data = pca....`.

Comment: @hpaulj is faster :)

Comment: @hpaulj You mean that ``self.data = pca.fit_transform(self.data[self.non_categorical])`` makes it a numpy array?

Comment: `pca.fit_transform` returns numpy array. Wasn't that your motivation to wrap `self.data` by `pd.DataFrame` in  `pd.DataFrame(self.data).head()` to make it work as a DataFrame? :)

Comment: @RaymondKwok To be honest, I guess so. Thing is, I just took a project from Github to see if it can be useful for my future music recommendation system and as you can see I barely have any idea on what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Ofcourse. At least the cause of the error is found. Good day @Neri-kun

Comment: @RaymondKwok Just because I found it doesn't automatically mean that I can solve it.

Comment: Ofcourse, this happens to me too.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(self.data).head()` doesn't change `self.data`.  It makes a dataframe and displays its `head`.  That's all.  Unfortunately, trying to use and tweak some code that you found online has many pitfalls if you have a bare understanding of the underlying language and packages (python, numpy, pandas).

Comment: @hpaulj Yep, I realized that now. And I agree with you, but it's weird that this code seemed to be supposed to work, since I took it from Github and the project seemed to be really documented.

Comment: @hpaulj Looks like I managed to solve my problem. Thanks for giving me this helpful hint :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem turned out to be, like @hpaulj said, that `pd.DataFrame(self.data).head()` line, because not only it was called for nothing, since it wasn't assigned to any variable, but also returned the first 5 rows, which makes sense now why I got a `KeyError` regarding the index after making a first change. So, instead, I changed it to `self.data = pd.DataFrame(self.data)` and now the code works as expected to.